# ERROR in multi ./src/app.js dist/app.bundle.js

Tags: webpack

I installed the `webpack` and `webpack-cli` in my project:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  }
```

But when I use the `webpack-cli` to package the `dist/app.bundle.js` I get bellow error:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli src/app.js dist/app.bundle.js 
Hash: a7d5a0d1ff2c17795899
Version: webpack 4.8.3
Time: 139ms
Built at: 2018-05-14 11:53:07
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/app.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
[1] multi ./src/app.js dist/app.bundle.js 40 bytes {0} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in multi ./src/app.js dist/app.bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dist/app.bundle.js' in '/Users/lll/Desktop/VueTest/hello-world'
 @ multi ./src/app.js dist/app.bundle.js
```

Answer (score 6):

In the `webpack 4`, you should add params for the command:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli src/app.js --output dist/app.bundle.js --mode development
```

add the `--output` param your issue will be solved.

You can also take a look at the [webpack output path](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path).